# Matching words from an array causes some vulnerabilities

Tags: php

Suppose there is a word in an array as "pan" and user typed a sentence which
contain a word as "pants" the program matches the word "pants" as "pan" please help me out, and for further information there are also some words in the array like "my valet","the nest" etc... need to be match.Thanks in advance.:)

```
  if($val['items']!=null){
     $items = explode(',',$val['items']);
     foreach($items as $k=>$item){
       if($item!='' && preg_match("/".preg_quote($item,"/")."/", $opText)){
         if(!in_array($item,$parameters[$val['name']],true)){
            $parameters[$val['name']][]=$item;
         }
       }
     }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a delimiter such as a space. Instead of searching for the word "pan" search for " pan ", when you search for words like "my valet" search for " my valet " instead. You also need to handle if it is the first word of the sentence in which case you ignore the first space. Does this resolve your issue?